# How prevent to auto-compilation loop with fswatch upon changes in Texmaker?

Tags: scripting, compiling, latex

After inspecting [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163211/compile-latex-source-automatically-on-creation-change#) and the unaccepted answer, I tried to test it. First I tested the recommended command with:

```
fswatch -o report.tex | xargs -n1 -I{} pdflatex report.tex
```

Which led to an infinite compilation loop, which I consider slightly inefficient, and furthermore, it does not create a long enough window-of-opportunity in which the PDF is accessible. So I tried to debug why `fswatch` yields an infinite compilation loop using a `ctrl+s` command in TexMaker in the `report.tex` file:

```
fswatch -o report.tex | xargs -n1 -I{} echo "hello world"
hello world
hello world
```

There I observed the `ctrl+s`/saving of the `report.tex` triggers two detected changes by `fswatch`. Furthermore, I tested it on a `f6` command in TexMaker, as well as on the `pdflatex report.tex` command, and observed `fswatch` detected 3 changes for both attempts:

```
fswatch -o report.tex | xargs -n1 -I{} echo "hello world"
hello world
hello world
hello world
```

The latter seems to be sufficient to cause the infinite compilation loop. Hence, I would like to ask, how can I ensure the `report.tex` is compiled once when a change is saved to it from TexMaker?

I think subquestions that may lead to a working answer may be as listed below, yet I did not find a satisfying answer to these:

- Does for example the fswatch have an argument to ignore changes for `n-miliseconds` or for the next `n-changes`?  It appears to me that section `3.2.3 Numeric Event Flags` of the `fswatch` [documentation](https://emcrisostomo.github.io/fswatch/doc/1.14.0/fswatch.pdf) seems to allow for only using the `n-th` event flag. Yet I did not yet successfully implement passing such an argument to inhibit compilation.
- Or are there arguments I could pass to the `pdflatex` report to reduce the three detected changes upon compilation to the `report.tex` to zero changes?
- Does TexMaker have an option to reduce the amount of changes to the `report.tex` from two to one upon saving with `ctrl+s`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fswatch` uses various backends depending on various OS. Let's assume the overall behavior is the same.

On my Linux system, attempts with `fswatch` (and option `-x`) give `PlatformSpecific` events which doesn't help to distinguish between a *read* event, a *write* event, an *open* event and a *close* event among many other possible events (note that Linux' *inotify* even distinguishes between two type of close events, one after no change, and one after changes, which would help further here). That's also why you get multiple events.

Reading from the source will trigger a compilation attempt, which will among other things *read again* this source. Loop created.

That's the cause of all your problems. You should trigger only on *write* events and also only once the file stops being written to, but `fswatch` considers all these events to be all *PlatformSpecific*. You need (a) tool(s) that can distinguish between the events, or else do periodic polls that compare dates or contents (I believe the last part is what is doing the accepted answer from OP's link).

You could use `fswatch` in `--one-event` mode without `xargs` combined with OP's linked accepted answer so `fswatch` doesn't get triggered again indefinitely but waits for `pdftex` to finish.. Of course you have to deal with race conditions when doing so in case you miss an event between.

As a conclusion: don't try to adapt everything to `fswatch`, change `fswatch` with a more adequate tool.

---

Example of alternate method on Linux (As this is specific OS related and OP didn't state an OS I'm going with this example).

`inotifywait` has the right options to monitor writes, and actual only end-of-write (so not MODIFY event, but only CLOSE_WRITE event). There might maybe be other things to check and adapt to when the file is actually moved, deleted and replaced, but I'm not attempting to figure out all the details. So:

```
inotifywait -m -e CLOSE_WRITE report.tex | xargs -n1 -I{} pdflatex report.tex
```

would be a good start.

To feed an event loop:

```bsh
inotifywait -m -r -e CLOSE_WRITE somedir | while read -r dir events filename; do
    if [ "$filename" != "${filename%.tex}" ]; then
        pdflatex "$dir/$filename"
    fi
done
```

could be a good start. Except...

Alas there are certainly caveats, starting with filenames including spaces or special characters. They could be further addressed for example with `--format` which appears to accept `\0` in the output (I don't think `--csv` is enough), but then the shell can't cope with this in a *read* loop. Sooner or later a non-shell tool using the *inotify* facility but not the *inotifywait* command would be better suited (eg: https://pypi.org/project/inotify/).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I verified your suggestion and noticed it also works on directories that only contained `.tex` and `.png` files: 
`inotifywait -m -e CLOSE_WRITE report.tex \
    Chapters/* \
    Appendices/* \
    Images/* \
     | xargs -n1 -I{} ./compile_script.sh
` where every ` \\` is followed by a new line.

Comment: The second (the event loop) checks the event is about a *.tex file. Anyway, again, the CLI tool's output isn't optimal to handle special characters in filenames.

Comment: +1.  also, you can use a Makefile to "compile" a pdf from its TeX source code if it has changed.  Run "make report.pdf" with a make rule saying that "report.pdf" depends on "report.tex" (and whatever else it needs) and can be built by running "pdflatex report.tex"